# Identity authentication making a policy that checks on a claim OR Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

A user with the claim "AcceptTermsAndConditions" can edit but an admin gets forbidden. The question is a user that has accepted the terms and conditions OR someone with the role admin can edit things. I don't really understand how I have to implement this or statement. So to summarize I have 2 roles a user who has to accept tos to edit things and a admin who can edit things because he has the role admin.

This is the Authorization in my startup class.
This is the code line I'm not sure what I need to put
"return registrationClaimValue == true.ToString() || role.RequireRole("admin").Equals(true);"

The purpose of this line of code is hat someone with the userRole has to accept the tos and thus has a claim with the value true in it. This works. But an admin does not have terms of services this value is null in the db but he still needs to be able to edit things. So the question is how can I do 2 checks one on a claim and a second on a role with an OR statement

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CanEdit",
                    policy =>
                    {
                        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                        {
                            var registrationClaimValue =
                                context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "AcceptTermsAndConditions")?.Value;

                            var role =
                                policy.RequireRole("admin");
                            return registrationClaimValue == true.ToString() || role.RequireRole("admin").Equals(true);
                        });
                    });
```

Here is my seeding data of my users

```c#
public static void Seed(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var usersToSeed = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
            var imiUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = "f18dcef5-4ba7-4e09-97ef-457c682c5d4a",
                ConcurrencyStamp = "ced460a4-3ea6-4246-8153-0f570cb1bcb8",
                SecurityStamp = "f5aabff3-db45-4a4a-92a6-bf5c8f37103f",
                Email = "user@imi.be",
                NormalizedEmail = "USER@IMI.BE",
                UserName = "user@imi.be",
                NormalizedUserName = "USER@IMI.BE",
                AcceptTermsAndConditions = true
            };
            usersToSeed.Add(imiUser);

            var imiRefuser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = "1fdbff31-c9cf-4b3c-9342-9b4be35c7a30",
                UserName = "refuser@imi.be",
                NormalizedUserName = "REFUSER@IMI.BE",
                Email = "refuser@imi.be",
                NormalizedEmail = "REFUSER@IMI.BE",
                EmailConfirmed = false,
                SecurityStamp = "bc255425-6e28-4ff5-bbe1-08af094b202f",
                ConcurrencyStamp = "58320226-0a8b-434a-bc57-9904399fcdf8",
                AcceptTermsAndConditions = false
            };
            usersToSeed.Add(imiRefuser);

            var imiAdmin = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = "89f94dbe-44be-41b7-afec-b5c7cbf7236a",
                ConcurrencyStamp = "a2520554-10fe-4ba2-aef7-1f9227c8dc4b",
                SecurityStamp = "658b6ac2-09f4-4f4a-a89b-f5463c1cf845",
                Email = "admin@imi.be",
                NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@IMI.BE",
                UserName = "admin@imi.be",
                NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN@IMI.BE"
            };
            usersToSeed.Add(imiAdmin);

            foreach (var user in usersToSeed)
            {
                user.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, "Test123?");
            }
            
            var adminRoleId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var adminRoleName = "admin";
            var userRoleId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var userRoleName = "user";
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = adminRoleId,
                Name = adminRoleName,
                NormalizedName = adminRoleName.ToUpper()
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = userRoleId,
                Name = userRoleName,
                NormalizedName = userRoleName.ToUpper()
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string> 
            { 
                RoleId = adminRoleId, 
                UserId = "89f94dbe-44be-41b7-afec-b5c7cbf7236a"
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string> 
            { 
                RoleId = userRoleId, 
                UserId = "1fdbff31-c9cf-4b3c-9342-9b4be35c7a30"
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string> 
            { 
                RoleId = userRoleId, 
                UserId = "f18dcef5-4ba7-4e09-97ef-457c682c5d4a"
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(usersToSeed);
        }
    }
```

Here is my api controller where i try to authorize the policy

```
//Update
        [HttpPut]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanEdit")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put(PlayerDetailResponseDto playerDetailResponseDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var playerDto = await _playersService.UpdateAsync(playerDetailResponseDto);
            return Ok(playerDto);
        }
```

Comment: And? What's the problem/question here?

Comment: @WiktorZychla A user with the claim "AcceptTermsAndConditions" can edit but an admin gets forbidden. The question is a user that has accepted the terms and conditions OR someone with the role admin can edit things. I don't really understand how I have to implement this or statement. So to summarize I have 2 roles a user who has to accept tos to edit things and a admin who can edit things because he has the role admin.

Comment: What's the name of your admin role? Is it `Admin` or `admin`?

Comment: You should edit your question with the information instead of commenting.

Comment: @WiktorZychla it's admin. In my database I have 2 AspNetRoles user and admin.

Comment: It is solved thanks for trying to help everyone :)